# Why does attaching touch listeners on an inflated layout not register touch events?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've run across a slightly funky behavior while developing my Android app and I was curious why it happens.  When I do the following no touch events are registered:

```
mInflatedLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
mInflatedLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Hello world");
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, when I do the following, I do get touch events registered:

```
mInflatedLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
mInflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.child_view)
    .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Hello world");
            return false;
        }
});
```

**Note**: The above code is psuedocode-ish rewriting of my actual app for simplicity's sake.  Feel free to ignore anything that would cause a compile time error.

My question is, why does this happen?  I am willing to guess there is something really simple going on here that I'm missing, but I'm a little baffled as to what that thing is.

**Edit**: This is the layout file that I'm using.  For what it's worth, the view itself is being displayed as the empty view of a ListView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header_view" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingRight="?baseGapSize"
    android:paddingLeft="?baseGapSize"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <CustomFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_white_rounded_rect_inactive"
        android:paddingBottom="?baseGapSize"
        android:paddingTop="?baseGapSize" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/StandardLightText" />
    </CustomFrameLayout>

    <CustomRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_white_rounded_rect_inactive" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/take_a_photo"
            android:paddingBottom="?baseGapSize"
            android:paddingTop="?baseGapSize"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_with_plus" />
    </CustomRelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe your `child_view` is covering the parent and also "eating" the touch events?

Comment: But if I don't define a touch listener on `child_view`, wouldn't it just pass its touch events up to its parent?

Comment: In certain cases no(like a EditText, TextView). You may want to post your layout file.

Comment: I've posted my layout above along with a little more info above.  Thanks for any insight you can give.

Answer (score 2):

Your Layout may not  not exposed - the whole screen may be occupied by child view so the Layout behind it is never accessible to touch.. or
you might have

```
android:clickable="true" //in childview
```

or

```
child_view.setClickable(true);
```

is causing your layout, not to fire touch event. Try removing this.

Comment: Neither of those is being called.  Even if that were the case, why wouldn't the touch event on one LinearLayout bubble up to its parent layout?